# chrome extension and tabs interactive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to let page interact with popup (browser action) contents?
like if I just type a word (ex.alpha) and when I click the button to send message, and the popup show what I just typed.
I think of parsing the whole page html to make it like this.
Is there another way to make a event(like dynamic add event at button) to notify chrome extension(popup)?

I only found the extension when I want to execute some code at tabs,but nothing can do with the page to extension.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript  (extension -> tab)

??? (tab -> extension)?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the onclick attribute of the element and then use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) in the event handler to communicate with your extension.

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood this before.